# How to get second last commit hash in git

Tags: git

I am using below git command to get last 2 commit hash

```
git log -n 2 --pretty=format:"%H"  #To get only hash value of commit
```

But I needs only second last commit hash.

Any help would be great

Thanks

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
git rev-parse @~
```

rev-parse turns various notations into hashes, `@` is current head, and `~` is the previous commit.

This generalizes to commits arbitrarily far back: for example, you can write `@~3` (or `@~~~`) to specify "three commits before the current head".

Comment: I think one crucial thing is missing here: the revision selector `@~` also accepts a number after the `~`, e.g. `@~3` means: the parent (`~`) of the parent of the parent (`3` times) of HEAD (`@`). ([see git documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection#_ancestry_references))

Comment: @Griddo should probably edit that in, as that is _insanely_ helpful.

Comment: Fair enough, @t0mgs. Not strictly necessary in a question about "the previous commit", but people might well get here looking for some other previous commit.

Comment: @amalloy i.e. moi, for example! :)

Comment: I prefer to use `HEAD` with index. i.e. to **last commit** I would use `git rev-parse HEAD~0`, to **penultimeate commit** `git rev-parse HEAD~1`, etc.

Answer (score 22):

Use `skip` attribute
`--skip=<number>` skips number commits before starting to show the commit output.

```
git log -n 1 --skip 1 --pretty=format:"%H"
```

Follow this [link](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html) for more info on `git log`

Comment: I like this more than the accepted answer, because I find this skip parameter very intuitive

Comment: Also works with git rev-list:
git rev-list --skip 1 -n1 HEAD

Answer (score 4):

You can just pipe the output of your command through [tail](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tail):

```
git log -n 2 --pretty=format:"%H" | tail -1
```